# How to add a VARRAY to an Oracle object

Tags: database, oracle, user-defined-types

I need to add a VARRAY called `menuNumbers` to an object type, `SpecialEvent_t` that is inherited from `Event_t`.

I'm a bit confusing about this part. I have referred to most of the currently available solutions within Stack Overflow, GitHub etc. However, none of these solutions have worked out successfully.

```
Event_t(
  EventID:char(5),
  EventType:varchar(20),
  VenueName:varchar(50),
  NoOfGuest:number(10)
) NOT FINAL

HotelEvent_t(
  Date:date,
  Price:numbr(8,2)
) UNDER Event_t

SpecialEvent_t(
  BookingDate:date,
  EndDate:date,
  MenuNumber:number(2),
  Reservation ref Reservation_t
) UNDER event_t
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your previous question you accepted an answer that ws essentially advising you to use relational tables instead of objects. Why are you looking at objects again - is that a requirement of your assignment? (And if so, I'm a bit confused about that previous acceptance...) Anyway, what have you tried - your best/closest attempt - and what was wrong with it?

Comment: I'm looking for how to show v array in schema its bit confusing. and   is v array is a data type and if we create one we arry can we use the  same v array type for diffident objects. as example. if i create v arry called phone number v array can i use the same varray to manager object and customer object.

Comment: yes its essensial for create objects for the assigments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `VARRAY` type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE numbers_varray AS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER(10,0);
```

Then you can use it in your types just like you would any other data-type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE Event_t AS OBJECT(
  EventID   char(5),
  EventType varchar(20),
  VenueName varchar(50),
  NoOfGuest number(10)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE HotelEvent_t UNDER Event_t (
  datetime date,                -- Date is a keyword, try to use a different name.
  Price  number(8,2)
);

CREATE TYPE SpecialEvent_t UNDER event_t (
  BookingDate date,
  EndDate     date,
  MenuNumbers  NUMBERS_VARRAY,
  Reservation ref Reservation_t
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3953d9ef9841b57a9a367c80aa91de0e)

Comment: thank you for the answer i think this well be helpful